# MCMC efficiency and nonlinear reparametrizations

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, references, markov-chain-montecarlo, parameterization

The efficiency (e.g., effective sample size per density evaluation) of most MCMC methods depends on the parametrization. 
However, so far I have come across little work in the MCMC literature that deals specifically with semi-automatically choosing a good parametrization, aside possibly of linear transformations that decorrelate the variables.

As an application, consider that most authors suggest to have *some* warm-up or burn-in period (with recommendations that go from 0% to 50% of the total number of samples). However, if an algorithm can use the information gathered during burn-in to re-parametrize the density and make the sampling more efficient, it might be even worth spending 80% of the time in multiple refined burn-in steps (see e.g. the [Stan reference guide](http://mc-stan.org/documentation/) about multiple burn-in steps).

Do you know of any work that proposes methods to choose (automatically or semi-automatically, i.e. with some human guidance) a *nonlinear* model re-parametrization at the end of burn-in?

For a *linear* transformation, for example, an algorithm could realign the axes according to the covariance of the points sampled towards the end of the warm-up phase.

Also, I specify "at the end of burn-in" because nonlinear adaptive methods will easily mess up with the Markov property and ergodicity, so let's keep things simple for the moment.

Comment: There is a large literature on parameterization in MCMC. It sounds like you want somebody to do a literature search for you. Have you done a scholar.google.com search for "mcmc parameterization"? There are many hits that appear relevant.

Comment: MCMC by itself is invariant to parametrisation in that if the target density is available for one parametrisation it is also available for another parametrisation, with obviously a wide range of freedom for the corresponding proposal distributions, so the burn-in/warm-up period can be used to compare several parametrisations in terms of effective sample size and expected square distance and range of likelihood values visited so far. I do not think one can come up with an automated reparametrisation.

Comment: @Xi'an: Thanks for the comments. They made me realize that my original question was misleading and unclear about (a) my state of knowledge and (b) what I was asking (essentially, I was not clear that my main focus was on the "semi-automated" part). E.g., I am aware of Jeffrey's prior, and I definitely did *not* mean that Bayesians do not care about parametrization (!). I cleaned up my question so that it's clear that what I ask is about techniques that actively exploit/attempt different parametrizations besides linear reparameterizations. (Perhaps such attempts are doomed from the start.)

Comment: I've used both linear and non-linear reparameterizations in particular circumstances for example in Gibbs or Metropolis-within-Gibbs sampling, but each time specifically tailored to the circumstances rather than automated (well, "specifically tailored" in form, but the specific coefficients could be different based on the data, and that part can be automated). However the nonlinear ones were usually to gain some other benefit, while at least some of the linear ones were deliberately to improve dependence in iterates by making the new axes more nearly align with a ridge in the parameter space.

Comment: My general philosophy about calibrating MCMC algorithms is to mix proposals and thus parameterisations in parallel or not as this takes advantage of all versions at once. If you wish for more structure, the burn-in stage can be exploited towards ranking or selecting those proposals. Changing axes towards less correlation is obviously one such natural step.